# PyTorch Geometric: What is the function utility to split train/validation/test for node classification

Tags: pytorch

I am new to PyTorch Geometric. I know there is a function that gives you the train, test, and validation node mask of a custom ratio in the node classification task. Does anyone know it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the function [AddTrainValTestMask](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/transforms.html#torch_geometric.transforms.AddTrainValTestMask)

Comment: and method removed :D

Answer (score 3):

It is `train_test_split_edges`. You can read more about it [here](https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utils.html?highlight=split#torch_geometric.utils.train_test_split_edges).